# Initializing ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>?

Tags: java, javafx-2, object-property, observablelist

I have a property which wraps an `ObservableList`. But I cannot figure out how to initialize it. Currently I am doing it like this

```
ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> property = new ChoiceBox<T>().itemsProperty();
```

which is obviously totally bad practice. Another one was

```
ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>();
```

but this needs later attention which I try to avoid to initialize the internal ObservableList with an empty List.

**I search for something like this**

```
ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>(new ObservableList<T>());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use ListProperty instead of ObjectProperty>

To initialize it do :
`ListProperty<Integer> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<Integer>(FXCollections.<Integer>observableArrayList());`

For more information you can read this article [ListProperty vs ObjectProperty](http://blog.dooapp.com/2013/06/listproperty-vs-objectproperty.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was sure I tried this one already, though I missed the generic instantiation of observableArrayList(). Thanks for pointing that out.